# Filling new column in a dataframe based on 3 values in df1 matching 3 values in df2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 2 data frames, both share the columns "*shoe*", "*size*", and "*color*". The smaller data frame contains each shoe model and has a column "*price*". The larger data frame contains every sold shoe but doesn't contain price (doesn't make sense I know but I'm just trying to explain my issue)

I'd like to find a way to compile a new column for shoe price in the larger data frame, which will take the shoe price from the smaller data frame for every match of the 3 shared columns "*shoe*", "*size*" and "*color*".

I've tried merges which don't work due to the different sizes, I've tried using a for loop but honestly, I'm still a beginner.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here's some code to generate dataframes with random data:

```
def Rand(start, end, num): 
res = [] 

for j in range(num): 
    res.append(random.randint(start, end)) 

return res


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"shoe":range(10), 
"size":range(1,11),"color":range(2,12),
'price':range(100,110)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"shoe": Rand(1, 10, 100),
"size": Rand(1, 11, 100), "color": Rand(1, 11, 100)})
```

Given the above dataframes, I'm trying to create a 'price' column in df2 that is found by matching df2's columns with matching values in the corresponding columns in df1

Comment: Can you create some sample data?

Comment: It's always better to have a concrete example, in this case the input dataframes and the expected output, than to only describe what you want in words.

Comment: I believe you need `df = df1.merge(df2, how='left')`

Comment: @jezrael year, I think simular

Comment: I just added code in the original post to help compile dataframes that can be used to help solve my problem. Let me know if you had any other questions I can help clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need this:

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.DataFrame({"shoe":range(10), "size":range(1,11),"color":range(2,12), 'price':range(100,110)})
file2 = pd.DataFrame({"shoe":range(100), "size":range(1,101),"color":range(2,102)})
df = pd.merge(file1,file2,how='right', on = ["shoe","size","color"])
df.head()
```

In this example you will get new dataframe, which merge matching three columns.
You can read more here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: It will match the 3 columns but from what I understand, it will not include the "price" column that we're after, given that we did a right merge and the price column is in the 'left' dataframe. Let me know if I've misunderstood anything about the merge

Comment: @Armon Try to use my example. To understand file1 this is your smaller dataframe, file2 is your big dataframe. Column 'price' will be included in df.

Comment: thanks, I was confused at first but just realized that the reason the merge didn't work was because one of the columns in one dataframe consisted of numbers astype(str), which messed up the merge :)

Comment: it seems that a merge hasn't properly kept the total number of rows from the larger data frame. The shape of the merged dataframe is substantially larger than both the smaller and larger dataframe; do you know how I can merge them so that the rows found in the new dataframe is the same as in the larger dataframe, with the only difference being the added column (of corresponding price in the example above)?

Comment: @Armon If you used your dataframes then you need to set the param `how`  to `right`. If big dataframe is in the left then `how` need to be changed to left (example `pd.merge(big_df,small_df,how='left'`)`